# Remove Sticky Header When Scrolling Up

Tags: jquery, sticky

I am using this [sticky header](https://github.com/m-danish-iqbal/sticky-header) plugin. The code triggers when user has scrolled down 800px, I would like to remove the sticky header effect when user is scrolling up and is 800px from top, right now it only removes the effect when page is scrolled almost to the top.

This is the code which triggers the plugin:

```
$('#header-middle').stickMe({
    topOffset: 800
});
```

The following code is custom code which toggles the header content with buttons:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if( $("#header-middle.primary").hasClass('sticking')) { 
        $('#header-middle.primary #header-main #header-search-form, #header-middle.primary #header-aside').hide();
        if(!visible) {
               $('body').find('#product-overview .process-button-group').clone().appendTo('#header-middle.primary #header-main');
            visible = true;
            }
    } else {
        $('#header-middle.primary #header-main #header-search-form, #header-middle.primary #header-aside').show();
        if(visible)  {
                $('#header-middle.primary').find('.process-button-group').remove();
                visible = false;
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show you html

Comment: @TSR, Thanks for looking into this. Basically I just need to trigger a event when user is scrolling from bottom to top and there is only 800px left to reach top and at this point I would like to trigger a event. Can you please tell me something like this - else if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800). Unfortunately this doesn't work as I expect.